# Snapping doesn't seem to work on multiple objects

Tags: objects, snapping

I've been trying to duplicate and move a pillar in a tutorial and can't get the incrementsnapping to work when i select an additional block next to it.

Snapping is fine on the individual pillar and the single block if I move them by themselves but when I try to move them together the snapping seems to be working with another grid and won't let me snap to the rest of it.

I have used the absolute grid snapping box checked and unchecked and it does the same thing

I'm sure its me doing something wrong but can't really make sense of it as it seems to work fine when I move them individually.

I've included some screenshots that hopefully make it easier to understand

[image: snapping fine at 14m]
[image: snaps fine to 16m]
[image: additional block at 10m]
[image: Pillar and block added]
[image: Pillar and block snapping to a seemingly different grid]

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be on the same tutorial (I don't know how he doesn't have the same problem). I played around with it for a bit, and I found that, after duplicating all the blocks, selecting an odd number of columns/columnless tiles seems to remove the problem. Just select different numbers of blocks until it snaps properly and you should be fine.

If worse comes to worst, just move the blocks individually, it's not as big of a headache compared to doing the same thing with vertices.

P.S. Don't forget to add the roof spacing blocks.

Comment: I actually solved this myself after playing around with it for about 2 days! If you press x, y or z it actually snaps it onto grid on that axis.  I'm not sure if that's what he does on the video but works a lot better than before